# Java equation / expression builder

Tags: java, expression, builder, equation

Is there any open source implementation in Java of a graphical expression builder or equation editor that one could use?

Something with an online demo or, at least, screenshots, would be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the type of equation.

If you're thinking of simple polynomials, you can try [Java Expression Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/jel/).

It's the first Google hit.